# A Laptop simulates an AP (access point)

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I'm using a laptop with Ubuntu (version 18.04) system to simulate an AP. Below is my python code. `hostapd.conf` file and `dnsmasq.confnew` file are in the same directory as the python file.

- A mobile phone or computer can discover this AP and connect to it
- The mobile terminal cannot scan the SSID of this AP and cannot connect to this AP

I want to know how to solve this problem.

```
import subprocess
import time
import textwrap
from scapy.all import *


def create_hostapd_conf(interface, ssid, password):
    # Create hostapd.conf content
    hostapd_content = textwrap.dedent(f"""
    interface={interface}
    driver=nl80211
    ssid={ssid}
    hw_mode=g
    channel=8
    ieee80211n=1
    wpa=2
    wpa_passphrase={password}
    wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    wpa_pairwise=CCMP
    rsn_pairwise=CCMP
    """).strip()
    # Write content to hostapd.conf file
    with open("hostapd.conf", "w") as hostapd_file:
        hostapd_file.write(hostapd_content)

        
def create_dnsmasq_conf(interface):
    # Create dnsmasq.conf content
    dnsmasq_content = textwrap.dedent(f"""
    interface={interface}
    dhcp-range=192.168.1.3,192.168.1.20,255.255.255.0,24h
    address=/#/192.168.1.2
    port=5353
    """).strip()
    # Write content to dnsmasq.conf file
    with open("dnsmasq.confnew", "w") as dnsmasq_file:
        dnsmasq_file.write(dnsmasq_content)

def start_ap(interface, ssid, password):
    # Configure hostapd
    subprocess.run(["sudo", "service", "network-manager", "stop"])
    subprocess.run(["sudo", "ifconfig", interface, "down"])
    subprocess.run(["sudo", "iw", "dev", interface, "set", "type", "__ap"])
    subprocess.run(["sudo", "ifconfig", interface, "up"])
    
    # Configure static ip
    subprocess.run(["sudo","ifconfig", "wlp3s0", "192.168.1.2", "netmask", "255.255.255.0"])

    # Start hostapd
    print("AAAAAAAAA")
    #subprocess.run(["sudo","airmon-ng", "check"])
    subprocess.run(["sudo","killall", "wpa_supplicant"])
    subprocess.run(["sudo", "service", "hostapd", "-B", "/home/celimuge/python-code/hostapd.conf"])
    time.sleep(2)
    #subprocess.run(["sudo","service", "hostapd", "start"])
    
    # Configure dnsmasq
    print("BBBBBBB")
    subprocess.run(["sudo", "dnsmasq", "-C", "/home/celimuge/python-code/dnsmasq.confnew"])
    
def stop_ap():
    # Stop hostapd and dnsmasq
    subprocess.run(["sudo", "service", "hostapd", "stop"])
    subprocess.run(["sudo", "service", "dnsmasq", "stop"])
    subprocess.run(["sudo", "killall", "dnsmasq"])
    subprocess.run(["sudo", "service", "network-manager", "start"])
    
def send_beacon_frame(interface, ssid):
    # Create a beacon frame
    beacon_frame = Dot11(type=0, subtype=8, addr1="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", addr2=get_if_hwaddr(interface), addr3=get_if_hwaddr(interface)) / Dot11Beacon(cap="ESS") / Dot11Elt(ID="SSID", info=ssid)

    # Send the beacon frame
    sendp(beacon_frame, iface=interface, inter=0.1, loop=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    interface = "wlp3s0"  # replace with your wireless interface
    ssid = "ap"
    password = "12345678"

    create_hostapd_conf(interface, ssid, password)
    create_dnsmasq_conf(interface)
    
    try:
        start_ap(interface, ssid, password)
        #send_beacon_frame(interface, ssid)
        print("CCCCCCCCC")
        time.sleep(150)  # Allow time for beacon frames to be sent
        print("\nStopping Access Point.")
        stop_ap()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nStopping Access Point.")
        stop_ap()
```